# How to replace the a font weight using google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Hello I try to detect specific string in my google doc and set it in "bold".
Ive tried this :

```
function bold() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var foundElement = body.findText("Câbles");

while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

    // Change the weight
    foundText.setFontWeight("bold");

    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText("Câbles", foundElement);
}
}
```

The script return me an error : TypeError: Fonction setFontWeight not found in Text object.

Can you help me? Thanks.

EDIT>

Ive tried using this, but the bold style was now applied to the whole paragraph not only the text string...

```
function bold() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var foundElement = body.findText("test");

while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

    // Set Bold
    foundText.setBold(true);

    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText("test", foundElement);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i did this :

```
function bold() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var foundElement = body.findText("test");

while (foundElement != null) {
    // Get the text object from the element
    var foundText = foundElement.getElement().asText();

    // Where in the element is the found text?
    var start = foundElement.getStartOffset();
    var end = foundElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    // Set Bold
    foundText.setBold(start, end, true);

    // Find the next match
    foundElement = body.findText("test", foundElement);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that is supported via sheets- not docs

in docs you could try to change font size?

```
 // Change the weight
   foundText.setFontSize(99);
```

Comment: Ive also tried "foundText.setBold(bold);"   its returning me "ReferenceError: "bold" not defined" :/

Comment: you will notice it is part of the documents class: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document

Comment: But not part of the sheets https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

Comment: Ive tried using foundText.setBold(true), its working but the bold style is applied to the full text paragraph, not only the text string.